# Event when firefox browser is focused/unfocused

Tags: firefox-addon

I was exploring MDN for a function that would tell me when the "browser loses focus" or "browser gets focus".  What I mean by this, is a user has multiple windows open, if a user switches to another window then "browser focus was NOT lost". Only if user clicks to like taskbar of windows/dockbar of mac or another app etc.

I came across `activate` and `deactivate` events which works great for windows, but not for browser.

I came across something called `UIEvent` but  I can't find much information on it just this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent